# Transferring .csv files through XBee Modules

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireless, transfer, xbee

We have set up a Monitoring System that can collect data. The system consists of several RPi's with attached accelerometers that log the data to a .csv file. 
The RPi's are so spread out that they are not in reach of eachother and their own created PiFY.

We use XBee S1 with Digimesh 2.4 for increased range to give the RPi's commands through XCTU. The XBee modules are set up as Routers. We can start and stop data collecting.

Now we are interested in transferring the collected data (.csv file) to a Master RPi. How can it be done through these XBee modules?

Comment: I think a little googling will help - but start with minicom on RPI - sample project at https://michael.bouvy.net/blog/en/2013/04/02/raspberry-pi-xbee-uart-serial-howto/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing any coding in Python, and using the pyserial module to send/receive data on the serial port.  It's fairly simple to get started with that.

Configure the routers in "AT mode" (also called "transparent serial mode") via `ATAP=0` with `DL` and `DH` set to 0 (telling it to use the coordinator as a destination for all serial data.

### Simple Coordinator Solution

Have the routers include some sort of node ID in each CSV record, and then configuring the coordinator in "AT mode" as well.  That way it will receive CSV records from multiple sources and just dump them out of its serial port.  As long as you send complete lines of data from each router, you shouldn't see corrupted CSV records on the coordinator.

### More Complicated Coordinator Solution

Configure the coordinator in "API mode" via `ATAP=1`.  Pick a programming language your comfortable with, like C, Java or Python and grab one of Digi's Open Source "host libraries" from their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/digidotcom).

The coordinator will receive CSV data inside of API frames so it can identify the source device that sent the data.  With this configuration, you can easily send data back to a specific device or make use of remote AT commands to change I/O on the routers.

Note that with either setup, there's no need for the RPi to create the file -- it can just send a CSV line whenever it has data ready.  Just make sure you're staging a complete line and sending it in a single "serial write" call to ensure that it isn't split into multiple packets over the air.